# Is there any short way in R to find min Max based on below data?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, range

I have two datasets. The first one is like this:

```
code | name
115  | A
120  | B
125  | A
130  | C
140  | A
```

The second one is like this:

```
code | Year
115  | 2015
140  | 2020
120  | 2017
130  | 2019
125  | 2011
```

Based on the column "code", I want to find the range of Year for each name like this:

```
code | Year | Range
115  | 2015 | 9
140  | 2020 | 9
120  | 2017 | 0
130  | 2019 | 0
125  | 2011 | 9
```

In fact, 9 is 2020-2011

My goal is to write a function with a minimum number of loops to work fast on a large number of data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the expected output, could you clarify? Why 120 and 130 is getting zero?

Comment: Both answers shown might be a correct solution but basically those are educated guesses. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to first merge the dataframes:

```
data<-merge(df1, df2, by = 'code')
```

Then you want the range of the year column, grouped by code:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(Range=diff(range(Year)))
```

This can all be done in a single call:

```
library(dplyr)

merge(df1, df2, by = 'code')%>%
group_by(name)%>%
mutate(Range=diff(range(Year)))

   code  Year name  Range
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1   115  2015 A         9
2   140  2020 A         9
3   120  2017 B         0
4   130  2019 C         0
5   125  2011 A         9
```

Comment: Thanks a milion, you think is there any way I can do this without adding names to the output data frame?

Comment: Just call ‘%>%select(-names)’ at the end

Answer (score 2):

1. `left_join` the dataframes by `code`
2. `group_by` `name`
3. use `max` and `min`

```
df <- tribble(
~code, ~name,
115, "A",
120, "B",
125, "A",
130, "C",
140, "A")

df1 <- tribble(
~code, ~Year,
115, 2015,
140, 2020,
120, 2017,
130, 2019,
125, 2011)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df, by="code") %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(Range = max(Year) - min(Year)) %>%
  select(-name)
df2
```

Output:

```
   code  Year name  Range
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1   115  2015 A         9
2   140  2020 A         9
3   120  2017 B         0
4   130  2019 C         0
5   125  2011 A         9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you think is there any way I can do this without adding names to the output data frame?